# How early can you enter USA after H1B visa extension

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, h1b-visas

My H1-B visa is already expired , however I have a valid I797A until Feb 2020 and have also applied for my extension. I would like to travel to my home country in December and understand that would need to get a new visa stamp in order to re-enter USA. I intend to apply for new H1-B visa with the H1B-extension I797A , can I re-enter the USA in JAN-2020 10 days prior to the start date on my new I797A which will be March 2020, or should I get a visa with the old I797A ( Feb 2020 ) ?

Answer (score 1):

US visas do not have a start date. You can enter the US the same day as the visa is stamped in your passport. Remember that it is the visa which allows you to travel to the US.